# Fetch request with map "Uncaught ReferenceError: is not defined" error

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

Why I can't get `${articlesData.results.map().join('')}` work on second part of code. But `const names = res.results.map(article => article.title).join('\n');` is working in first part?

How can I get it work in second part of code as well?

```
const articlesData = fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2')
   .then(res => res.json())
   .then(res => {
      res.data.map(article => {
         console.log(`${article.degree} ${article.title}`);
         const names = res.data.map(article => article.title).join('\n');
      });
   });
 


document.getElementById('js-card').innerHTML = `
<p> ${articlesData.data.map().join('')} </p>
`
```

I found other somewhat similar questions but answers didn't work.

Comment: What's the point of `map` in this case?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: What makes you think that `articlesData` contains the response data?

Comment: Btw you are not returning anything in the `map` bro

Comment: Try adding `return names` under the line `const names....`

Comment: I left map blank intentionally for cleaner code. I want to render html with this data.
@DominikMatis, could you please share a code?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm on a mobile, but to put it briefly you have response as res in an arrow function, running map() with doing nothing and out of map you are returning also nothing. So the res does not get out of that "then" clause, you need at least put return res before last});